# PHP inhertience method referencing

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php
class A {
    private function foo() {
        echo "baf!<br/>";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();

    }
}


class C extends A {
    private function foo() {
        echo "bar!<br/>";
    }

}

$c = new C();
$c->test();  //Prints baf!
?>
```

How to make `c->test()` to print bar! ? I was expecting that `foo()` will be overridden in `C` and would print bar! can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By making both methods protected you will achieve the desired result; the reason being that within `A::test()` it can only resolve `$this->foo()` to `A::foo()` because of the `private` visibility.  See [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility).

```
class A {
    protected function foo() {
        echo "baf!<br/>";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();

    }
}


class C extends A {
    protected function foo() {
        echo "bar!<br/>";
    }

}

$c = new C();
$c->test();  //Prints bar!
```

Comment: @prakharsingh95 No, it must also be `protected` like in class `A`.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 property and methods can be higher visibility or same visibility in inherited class, but it cant be lower visibility. otherwise it will show fatal error

Comment: Thanks Jack and @fallenAngel Indeed this will violate https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle. You could still get away with this in C++, so I assumed that would be the case.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I hope i am not asking much, can you please elaborate step by step by call stack? I am still bit confused here.

Comment: @fallenAngel When you call `$c->test()` it calls `A::test()` in the context of `C`; when it needs to resolve `$this->foo()` it will check `C::foo()` first but it has private visibility in `C` so it moves up to `A` and finds it there. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    protected function foo() {
        echo "baf!<br/>";
    }
    public function test() {
        $this->foo();

    }
}


class C extends A {
    protected function foo() {
        echo "bar!<br/>";
    }

}
$c = new C();
$c->test();  //Prints baf!
```

just make both the foo function as public or protected access level.